# Using SMB shares as docker volumes

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and docker-compose.
I'm trying to run a service using docker-compose on my Raspberry PI. The data this service uses is stored on my NAS and is accessible via samba.
I'm currently using this bash script to launch the container:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=test,password=test //192.168.0.60/test /mnt/test
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
```

Where the `docker-compose.yml` file simply creates a container from an image and binds it's own local `/home/test` folder to the `/mnt/test` folder on the host.

This works perfectly fine, when launched from the script. However, I'd like the container to automatically restart when the host reboots, so I specified 'always' as restart policy. In the case of a reboot then, the container starts automatically without anyone mounting the remote folder, and the service will not work correctly as a result.

What would be the best approach to solve this issue? Should I use a volume driver to mount the remote share (I'm on an ARM architecture, so my choices are limited)? Is there a way to run a shell script on the host when starting the docker-compose process? Should I mount the remote folder from inside the container?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? What init system does it have? I would recommend, if possible using systemd dependencies to manage this.

Comment: It's OSMC, which is based on Debian. I was thinking that a solution using docker itself would be preferable, as it would be more portable and less reliant on external host configuration, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally "solved" my own issue by defining a script to run in the `/etc/rc.local` file. It will launch the mount and docker-compose up commands on every reboot.

Being just 2 lines of code and not dependent on any particular Unix flavor, it felt to me like the most portable solution, barring a docker-only solution that I was unable to find.

Thanks all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best approach to solve this issue?

As @Frap suggested, use `systemd` units to manage the mount and the service and the dependencies between them.

[This document](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba#As_systemd_unit) discusses how you could set up a Samba mount as a systemd unit.  Under Raspbian, it should look something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount Share at boot
After=network-online.target
Before=docker.service
RequiredBy=docker.service

[Mount]
What=//192.168.0.60/test
Where=/mnt/test
Options=credentials=/etc/samba/creds/myshare,rw
Type=cifs
TimeoutSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Place this in `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-test.mount`, and then:

```
systemctl enable mnt-test.mount
systemctl start mnt-test.mount
```

The `After=network-online.target` line should cause systemd to wait until the network is available before trying to access this share.  The `Before=docker.service` line will cause systemd to only launch docker after this share has been mounted.  The `RequiredBy=docker.service` means that if you start `docker.service`, this share will be mounted first (if it wasn't already), and that if the mount fails, docker will not start.

This is using a credentials file rather than specifying the username/password in the unit itself; a credentials file would look like:

```
username=test
password=test
```

You could just replace the `credentials` option with `username=` and `password=`.

> Should I mount the remote folder from inside the container?

A standard Docker container can't mount filesystems.  You can create a privileged container (by adding `--privileged` to the `docker run` command line), but that's generally a bad idea (because that container now has unrestricted root access to your host).